# Certain Symbols not printed by Evince (or lp) but OK with acroread

Tags: fonts, printing, evince

I am trying to print a PDF file that contains some symbols. It is shown perfectly on screen by both acroread and evince. However, printing through evince leads to square boxes around where the symbol (a sub-scripted 1/2) should be. I get the same poor result using lp. I have seen this problem in the past for various special characters: ff, parts of equations etc.

This appears to be working on a colleagues version of evince under gentoo.

All fonts are claimed to be included (and, evidently, aren't a problem when displaying on screen):

```
  pdffonts ~/output.pdf 
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  UKUJEM+JFBVIY+ArialMT                CID TrueType      yes yes yes      5  0
  FEHSZY+LTXGIV+TimesNewRomanPSMT      CID TrueType      yes yes yes      6  0
  AIMHGU+YMOTNN+TimesNewRomanPSMT      CID TrueType      yes yes yes      7  0
```

`
The printer is a HP CP 2025.

Comment: Are the pdf readers you are comparing on the same system? Can they reach the same fonts?

Comment: yes - all on the same system. It somehow seems that acroread knows something about printing that lp and evince doesn't... Very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work-around that solves this problem:

Change of driver from

```
HP Color LaserJet CP2020 Series with Duplexer Postscript [en] (recommended)
```

to

```
HP Color LaserJet cp2025dn pcl3, hpcups 3.11.1 [en]
```

seems to do the trick for unknown reasons. (But I'm happy that it works) No downsides detected yet.